Is there a race condition in bash when terminating a script with a subprocess with a signal?
#!/bin/bash

( sleep 10; echo foo; )
echo bar


start to run the code
during the sleep, send SIGINT (Ctrl+C)
is there a chance of ever seeing "bar" on the output?

The reasoning being:
() creates a subprocess, which processes the signal first, so the main bash process sees that the command has returned, and executes the next line of code before getting to process the SIGINT.
A variation:
#!/bin/bash

( sleep 10; echo foo; ) &
wait -f
echo bar

This is not something I have seen, or a possible bug, etc, I just want to know, how this is supposed to work?
I think, that the SIGINT is propagated from the parent process to the child, and thus the main bash process should be aware of the signal by the time the subprocess returns, so the echo bar is never executed, but this is just what I expect, and maybe not what actually happens.
(bash version 5)
EDIT:
Experiment with Ctrl+C and backgrounded subshell:
#!/bin/bash

( sleep 100; echo foo; ) &
wait -f
echo bar

Result:
$ bash
$ ./bla.sh
^C
foo
$

In another shell:
$ ps x | grep 'sleep 100'
  28960 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep sleep 100
[./bla.sh]
$ ps x | grep 'sleep 100'
  28996 pts/1    S+     0:00 sleep 100
  29010 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep sleep 100
[Ctrl+C
$ ps x | grep 'sleep 100'
  29048 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep sleep 100
$ 


"I think, that the SIGINT is propagated from the parent process to the child" – Upon Ctrl+C the terminal driver sends SIGINT to the foreground process group and there is no propagation. See this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743030/108618


#!/bin/bash

( sleep 10; echo foo; )
echo bar


start to run the code
during the sleep, send SIGINT (Ctrl+C)
is there a chance of ever seeing "bar" on the output?


Yes, if the subshell or the command running within it at the time you press Ctrl+C ignores or handles the SIGINT and doesn't report a death by SIGINT to its shell parent like in:
( sh -c 'trap : INT; sleep 10; exit'; echo foo; )
echo bar

( trap : INT; sleep 10; echo foo )
echo bar

Where you see both foo and bar if pressing Ctrl+C whilst sleep is still running.

The reasoning being:
() creates a subprocess, which processes the signal first, so the
main bash process sees that the command has returned, and executes the
next line of code before getting to process the SIGINT.

Not exactly. When you press Ctrl+C whilst that script is running as a foreground job of an interactive shell in a terminal, the SIGINT is sent to the whole process group, so it's sent to all 3 running processes at the time:

the process that executed bash
the process running the subshell
the process running sleep.

bash like a few other shells however does a very special processing of SIGINT (and SIGQUIT): the wait and cooperative exit behaviour described at https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html (and whether it's the "proper" behaviour is debatable and debated; see Unable to stop a bash script with Ctrl+C as an example of that behaviour causing some annoyance for instance).
bash processes, when they receive a SIGINT, wait to see whether the process they're waiting for have died of a SIGINT (has been interrupted) to decide whether they should die and report they've been interrupted themselves (by killing themselves again with a SIGINT) or not.
In your case, sleep was killed and returned with an exit status indicating it had been killed, so the subshell process kills itself with SIGINT, and same happens in the parent process.
In my first case, sleep dies, sh (which in my case is not bash; but the effect would be the same with bash) receives the SIGINT but handles it and does nothing and returns normally, so bash considers  it has not been interrupted, so just ignores the SIGINT it received itself.
Same in my second case, where SIGINT is handled by bash in the subshell this time.

A variation:
#!/bin/bash

( sleep 10; echo foo; ) &
wait -f
echo bar

This is not something I have seen, or a possible bug, etc, I just want
to know, how this is supposed to work?

That's simpler.  Not that it matters here, but in bash like in most Bourne-like shells, SIGINT (and SIGQUIT) is ignored in asynchronous commands (those started with &), so you'll find that sleep is still running after you press Ctrl+C.
But the bash parent process does receive its own SIGINT whilst it's running the wait builtin, and just dies as a result, the same way it dies when receiving SIGINT in any of its builtins.

On the last part of your answer and my second case, the backgrounded subshell: I checked it in my shell and Ctrl+C kills everything: the foreground and the background process, no sleep remains. I made sure I actually use a bash shell. I trapped SIGINT to make sure that that is what Ctrl+C sends. I have also checked my .bashrc, but nothing stood out as relevant in this matter. Could you confirm the behaviour you described on your system?

I just checked the same with SIGTERM, in which case it works as you have described.

Reading through the source you have kindly provided about "wait and cooperative exit", SIGTERM is not under the umbrella of this behaviour. In this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34225945/7025033 , it is claimed that SIGTERM is not propagated, and this is indeed what I see when I tested it. Even if the subshell of sleep is not backgrounded, only the main shell is terminated, the sleep keeps on running. So, if SIGTERM were to be sent to the whole process group, there would be a race condition, the outcome depends on the order in which the processes are terminated.

@ZoltanK. there is no propagation, whatever that means, just that ^C causes SIGINT to be sent to the foreground process group, all processes in that group. If you send SIGTERM to the whole process group, as with kill -- "-$pgid", you'll see all processes dying, and if the shell is waiting for a process that handles/ignores that signal, you'll see bash does not treat it specially like it does for SIGINT/SIGQUIT
